# custom button visibility based on field

Tags: button, custom

I have a custom button but it has to be displayed in the page only when a picklist value is selected. 
How to obtain this?

Comment: where is the button located? On a standard page layout or a visualforce page?

Comment: Let us know what page are you referring to here: Custom VF page or Standard page?

Comment: The button is on the VF page

Comment: If you have to handle the display of a button on the vf page,you can handle it in many ways.What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a formula to do the trick. For more info, see [How do I create a custom button to appear in a field?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004375)

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(MyPicklist__c, "Desired Value"),
    HYPERLINK(
        "/apex/MyPage?id=" & Id,
        IMAGE(
            "/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01530000001Fmb3&oid=00D30000000ehPe&lastMod=1276195061000",
            "Button Fallback Text"
        )
    )
    null
)
```

Obviously you will have some different ids in your image url.

Comment: it's a nice one

Comment: Interesting, but it can only be placed on the details section of the page layout.  Not on the buttons section, or may be I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mahmood That is correct.

Comment: What I got from the question is, the user wants to hide/unhide a button based on a field value change. Now, this will have two scenarios, if a standard page layout , your solution will work and one mentioned with record types will also work, although it would be overkill. But in case of custom vf, we could use js to achieve that.

Comment: I agree `RecordType` may be overkill here, though potentially viable. Yes a custom `Visualforce Page` would simplify things drastically. I assumed OP was asking about `Page Layout` but we will see.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 recordtypes and 2 pagelayouts.

Lets say:

`RecordType1` and `PageLayout1` where custom button will be displayed.

`RecordType2` and `PageLayout2` where custom button will not be displayed.

Create `Workflow rule` and `Field Update` where based on Picklist value selection and update the `RecordType`.

You can do the same Field Update through `Process Builder`.